# React post , what is possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios, fetch

how to succeed at post title and price ?

I can not get back the title and the price, in my database, an idea of ​​how to do?

I am looking to add the title and price of different products with a button

I hope I have correctly expressed my problem

of course sorry for my english and the quality of my code
can you help me pls

```
class Cart extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: '',
        price:'',

    };

}


getRandom = async () => {

    const res = await axios.get(
        'http://localhost:5252/api/bieres'
    )
    this.setState({ data: res.data })
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.getRandom()
}

submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
}    
handleSubmit = async (ev) =>
{
 ev.preventDefault();
 const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
 await delay(5000);
 const config = {

   method: "POST",
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
 };

 const url = "http://localhost:5252/api/alluserpls";


 fetch(url, config)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res => {
     if (res.error) {
       alert(res.error);
     } else {
       alert(`ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
     }
   }).catch(e => {
     console.error(e);

   });
   this.setState({ redirect: true })
  }

render() {

    let addedItems = this.props.items.length ?
        (
            this.props.items.map(item => {
                return (
                    <div className="homeProduct2">


                        <Media key={item.id}  >

                            <Media body className="mediaBodyContainerHome">
                        <div className="containerForCartMediaPaddingForCart">                         
                            <div className="mediaBodyTitle">
                                <Media heading className='MediaTextHome'>
                                    {item.title}
                                </Media>
                                <Media className='MediaTextHome2'>
                                {item.price} €
                            </Media>
                            </div>         
                            </Media>
                            </div>

                                </div>
                            </Media>


                        </Media>

                        <div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        ) :

        (

            <Container className="containerCartContainerCart"  >
                <CardText className='panierCardTextCartPanier'>Oops !</CardText>
            </Container>
        )

    return (

        <div onSubmit={(ev) => this.handleSubmit(ev)}>

            <div className="collection">
            <form
      method="post"
      onSubmit={event => this.handleSubmit(event)}>
             <span> {addedItems} </span>    </form>
            </div>

        <div>



        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
      }
           export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart)
```

Comment: `I can not get back the title and the price, in my database` Do you meen your APi doesn't return the id ?

Comment: As I understand your problem, I think you have to assign your response values to the state.
this.setState({ title: res.title, price: res.price });

Comment: for my GET I have no worries, 
it's really for post title and price

Comment: Are you getting the correct response from the server?

Comment: are you running your react app on port 5252 like the api or is it on a different port?

Comment: What happens when you run your React app? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Koga ,
can you give me more details? or an example ? 
I have a correct answer only empty.

Comment: are you running your react app on port 5252 like the api or is it on a different port? 
a different port , not probleme when i run my app